# Appium and Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appium

I am new to Appium and I have installed Appium on ubuntu and make my first test using java command in an Eclipse while running my test I get an error: A new session could not be created.permission to start activity denied.
please Advice.

Here is my code:

```
public class BoxerTest {
    AndroidDriver dr;

    @Test
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","TA09402ERN");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","5.0.2");
        cap.setCapability("platformAndroid","Android");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage","com.boxer.browser");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity","com.boxer.browser.MainActivity");

        dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL ("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);    
    }

    @After

    public void End(){
        dr.quit();
   }
}
```

Comment: could you share a the block of logs from Appium server along with the failurer

Comment: share appium server logs

Comment: If you are using appium version 1.4.16+  , then remove   cap.setCapability("appPackage","com.boxer.browser");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity","com.boxer.browser.MainActivity"); caps. By the way you need to specify apk path capability

Comment: File app = new File("apk-path");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app);

Comment: info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.7 (REV 3b1a3b3ddffa1b74ce39015a7a6d46a55028e32c)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session

Comment: error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Permission to start activity denied.
info: [debug] Error: Permission to start activity denied.
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/nitish/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:1151:19)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/nitish/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/adb.js:180:9)

Comment: info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Permission to start activity denied.)","origValue":"Permission to start activity denied."},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500

Comment: I am using this video to learn as a example.here is the link:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3rykwz3hMA

Answer (score 0):

Launchable app activity might be wrong. To get the launchable activity, take the APK and run the command `aapt dump badging <boxer.apk>`